# Programatically converting images to cartoon and oil paint images in android

Tags: android, image

How to convert images to cartoon and oil paint images?

Is there any library for this?

Comment: maybe you need to implement your own custom library. You can find how can you implement this based on open project called "Paint.Net", has many plugins to modify an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably want to look into general non-photorealistic rendering (NPR) algorithms.

[This site](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/npr/) has many links to excellent papers regarding a variety of NPR techniques. Oil painting is particularly difficult as making it look perfect would likely involve some fluid simulation, but you can most likely fake it (probably similarly to older paint programs' filters to emulate it).

Toon shading would likely be a posterization technique with some edge detection. A lot of tweaking would be involved to make it suitable for general-purpose use in converting any photograph/image.

Comment: have you any examples of the implemented demo?