# Convert photo to cartoon in android by programmatically?

Tags: android, image-processing

I am searching the demo, source code, in android for convert photo to cartoon in android by programmatically. I take reference of existing stack overflow answer but noting help . i followed the link [Programatically converting images to cartoon and oil paint images in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620387/programatically-converting-images-to-cartoon-and-oil-paint-images-in-android)
                                        but No solution Any Idea?

Comment: The more naïve results you expect the more advanced the solution will be. If you don't find a library that has already implemented this, you'll need to do edge detection, color quantization and saturation... at least.

Comment: Hi, @rick have you got any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer this library from github https://github.com/ragnraok/android-image-filter. It provides several options to modify the images. So, go through this library.

Comment: That image filters not like cartoon filters.